# having issue applying even odd selector in css

Tags: html, css

I have a DOM structure like this

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6"><span>1.</span>
    <div class="input_wrap">
      <input type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6"><span>2.</span>
    <div class="input_wrap">
      <input type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried to use this css

```
.input_wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  &:nth-child(even) input {
    background: red !important;
  }
  input {
    width: 97%;
    margin-left: 3%;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
}
```

why has the even selector affected both input elements? I want to select all the left side's input to be red.

Answer (score 1):

see this code

```css
.col-sm-6:nth-child(even) input {
    background: green !important;
  }
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6"><span>1.</span>
    <div class="input_wrap">
      <input type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6"><span>2.</span>
    <div class="input_wrap">
      <input type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

so nth child looks for every element with respect to its parent..

so both of your `input_wrap` are 2nd child of their corresponding parents thats why both of them get matched

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to make all the "left side" inputs red:

```
.col-sm-6:first-child input{
  background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`nth-child` is only applying to elements inside the same parent. So if you want to select all even inputs per row just do: `.row > [class^="col"]:nth-child(even) input`.

If you want just the first input be red use:
`[class^="col"]:first-child input`

Answer (score 0):

In fact you need this selector:

```
.col-sm-6:nth-child(even) input {
    background: red !important;
  }
```

because `.input_wrap` is ALWAYS the second child inside its parent, so your original rule is applied to every `.input_wrap` instance, and therefore to *every* input field. So you shouldn't "count" the `.input_wrap` for your selection, but their parent elements (`.col-sm-6`), and after that add the input selector, as I did it in the solution above.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZeOVQg

Addition: You wrote: "I want to select all the left side's input to be red."  That would be `odd` ones, like

```
.col-sm-6:nth-child(odd) input {
    background: red !important;
  }
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qrNLaa